Char information is saved as strange letters
I'm trying to write code that can insert, consult and delete any information in a .txt document, but when I insert my information on C console, every information is saved as strange letters and symbols like that:
                        Q(@     `$@     1       P            ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ1           

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Dados
{
    char ID[2];
    char NOME[50];
    char EMAIL[50];
    char TELEFONE[14];
    char STATUS[1]; 
} Dados;

Dados GetDados()
{
    Dados dados;
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\nDigite o ID: ");
    scanf("%s", dados.ID);
    
    printf("\n\nDigite seu primeiro nome: ");
    scanf("%s", dados.NOME);
    
    printf("\n\nDigite o Email: ");
    scanf("%s", dados.EMAIL);
    
    printf("\n\nDigite o Telefone: ");
    scanf("%s", dados.TELEFONE);
    
    rewind(stdin);
    return dados;
}


void ConsultarPorID(char ID[]) {
    FILE * arq;
    Dados dados;
    int encontrou = 0;

if ((arq = fopen("c:\\pastadados\\newdados.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo.\n");
    return;
}
while (fscanf(arq, "%s%s%s%s", dados.ID, dados.NOME, dados.EMAIL, dados.TELEFONE) != EOF) {
    if (strcmp(dados.ID, ID) == 0) {
        printf("\n\tId: %s\n", dados.ID);
        printf("\tNome: %s\n", dados.NOME);
        printf("\tEmail: %s\n", dados.EMAIL);
        printf("\tTelefone: %s\n", dados.TELEFONE);
        encontrou = 1;
    }
}
if (!encontrou) {
    printf("Nenhum rsegistro encontrado com o ID '%s'.\n", ID);
}
fclose(arq);
}


int main()
{
    FILE * arq;
    Dados dados;
    char ID[2];
    char NOME[50];
    char EMAIL[50];
    char TELEFONE[14];
    char STATUS[1];
    int resposta, idConsulta;
    
    printf("\n1 - Inserir dados\n\n2 - Consultar por ID\n\n3 - Consultar por nome\n\n4 - Consultar por email\n\n5 - Consultar por telefone\n\n6 - Excluir dados\n\n\nQue opcao deseja prosseguir? ");
    scanf("%d", &resposta);
    
    if(resposta == 1)
    {
        if ((arq = fopen("c:\\pastadados\\newdados.txt", "a")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("\n\nNao foi possivel criar o arquivo! :(\n\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else 
        {
            do {
                GetDados();
                fwrite(&dados, sizeof(Dados), 1, arq);
                printf("\n\nDados salvos com sucesso!\n");
                printf("\nDeseja inseir mais dados? (s/n): ");
                resposta = getche();
            } while (resposta != 'n' && resposta != 'N');
            fclose(arq);
        }
    }

    else if (resposta == 2) {
        system("cls");
        printf("Digite o ID que deseja consultar: ");
        scanf("%d", &idConsulta);
        
        fgets(ID, 2, stdin);
        ID[strcspn(ID, "\n")]; 
        
        ConsultarPorID(ID);
    }
    
    else if (resposta == 6) {
        remove("c:\\pastadados\\newdados.txt");
        printf("\nDados excluidos com sucesso!");
    }
    return 0;
}

    


I don't know, maybe this bug is in the Char string

Since you write the struct with fwrite(&dados, sizeof(Dados), 1, arq); you should probably read it the same way.

You're saving it as a binary file, but reading it as a text file.

so my code can read these stranger letters because your structure?

See How to avoid scanf() causing a buffer overflow in C?  Your ID had better be a single character, and your user(s) had better not type more than one (non-space) character before the newline.

Using rewind(stdin); is surprising and probably wrong.

Aside: what do you hope to achieve with fgets(ID, 2, stdin); ID[strcspn(ID, "\n")];? The member char ID[2] can only hold a single newline plus string terminator. And the second instruction looks like an attempt to remove the newline, but does nothing. Even if it did, you'd have an empty string.

@JonathanLeffler: rewind(stdin) is well-defined and correct in the Microsoft C runtime library: "To clear the keyboard buffer, use rewind with the stream stdin, which is associated with the keyboard by default." However, you are correct that the ISO C standard does not specify what should happen in this case. Related: Using fflush(stdin)

@AndreasWenzel Whether or not rewind(stdin) is well-defined is not the issue.  Users expect a program that reads from stdin to treat it as a stream.  Any program that relies on rewinding stdin and reading data multiple times will have surprising behavior when stdin is not a regular file, and users will (rightly) interpreted the behavior as "wrong".   rewind(stdin) is definitely surprising, and probably wrong.

@WilliamPursell: You wrote: "Any program that relies on rewinding stdin and reading data multiple times will have surprising behavior when stdin is not a regular file" -- As pointed out in my previous comment, rewind(stdin) is the way recommended by Microsoft to "clear the keyboard buffer" when using the Microsoft C runtime library. OP appears to be using Microsoft Windows and appears to want to remove the dangling newline character (and any other characters) that scanf left in the keyboard buffer. Therefore, what OP is doing appears correct to me, albeit non-portable.

@WilliamPursell: When you wrote "will have surprising behavior when stdin is not a regular file", did you maybe mean the opposite of what you wrote? Did you maybe mean when it is a regular file, instead of is not a regular file? In that case, I agree with you. However, in my opinion, that makes Microsoft's decision questionable to make rewind(stdin) the recommended way to clear the keyboard buffer, and not so much OP's decision to follow that recommendation (unless OP's code is intended to be portable or OP wants to accept input from sources other than the keyboard).

When I see "rewind(stdin)", I assume the author is intending the user to invoke the program with stdin directed from a regular file, and the rewind is there to enable re-reading data.  This is a bad practice, but not unheard of.  In that scenario, the program works as expected when stdin is a regular file, but fails when stdin is not a regular file.  When doing this sort of thing, it is better to explicitly seek and check the result.
